# How to start an interactive shell with docker container using restful API?

Tags: docker, rest

I'm trying to learn about the Docker Engine restful API, v1.41, but that's a problem. I managed to use cURL successfully to send all HTTP requests concerning containers, images, volumes and network, but it's impossible to me to use them for exec instances.

I read in the official documentation that when I use the `docker exec` command, he behaves the same way as calling `POST /containers/:id/exec` and then `POST /exec/:id/start`.

Now, in order to execute `docker exec -it my_container bash` that's what I did and got:

```
[claudio@gulliver ~]$ curl -X POST --unix-socket /run/docker.sock\
http/containers/18d7dee7470d/exec\
-H "Content-Type: application/json"\
-d '{
    "AttachStdin":true,
    "AttachStdout": true,
    "AttachStderr": true,
    "Tty": true,
    "Cmd":["bash"]
}'

{"Id": "853938b2621606f85c04409ec7e345b884d46b95985a4fca0e8ddf28e20e1f79"}
```

```
[claudio@gulliver ~]$ curl -X POST --unix-socket /run/docker.sock\
http/exec/853938b2621606f85c04409ec7e345b884d46b95985a4fca0e8ddf28e20e1f79/start\
-H "Content-Type: application/json"\
-d '{
    "Detach":false,
    "Tty":true
}' --verbose

Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying /run/docker.sock:0...
* Connected to http () port 80 (#0)
> POST /exec/853938b2621606f85c04409ec7e345b884d46b95985a4fca0e8ddf28e20e1f79/start HTTP/1.1
> Host: http
> User-Agent: curl/7.85.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 28
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/vnd.docker.raw-stream
< Api-Version: 1.41
< Docker-Experimental: false
< Ostype: linux
< Server: Docker/20.10.21 (linux)
* no chunk, no close, no size. Assume close to signal end
<
```

And from now I cannot do anything, just interrupt the process.

Is there a way I don't know to interact with this?